# Populate a combobox on a userform from cell values

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

How does one populate a combobox (on a userform) from cell B2 to however many the user chooses to enter.

Comment: Here's a useful guide: http://www.contextures.com/xlUserForm02.html#ListCombo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a column of values:

```
Me.myCombo.List = Worksheets("mySheet").Range("B2:B100").Value
```

For a row of values:

```
Me.myCombo.List = Application.Transpose( _
          Worksheets("mySheet").Range("B2:M2").Value)
```

Comment: How would you populate the combobox across a row instead of a collumn?

Comment: Also you can use   Me.myCombo.AddItem("My item value") if you need to run through the items sequentially or add to an existing list.