# Populate Userform combobox from a given range on a mac (excel 2011)

Tags: excel, combobox, populate, userform

How do you populate a combobox with values from a given range on a mac. I have been searching for answers for the last hour but none of the solutions seem to be working. I have a userform called `Details` and a combobox called `CurrencyList` that I would like to populate with values from `A23:A30`. There is no rowsource property that I can find. I tried using the answer from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038589/populate-a-combobox-on-a-userform-from-cell-values) as follows:

```
Private Sub Details_Initialize()
Me.CurrencyList.List = Worksheets("mySheet").Range("A23:A30").Value
End Sub
```

but the combo box comes up empty.

Thank you for any help, Im sure its a very easy question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer with:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
CurrencyList.List = Worksheets("mySheet").Range("A23:A30").Value
End Sub
```

My mistake was changing `UserForm` to the name of my specific userform (`Details`)