# Populating a combobox on a userform from a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate a `combobox` with a range of cells from another sheet in my workbook (called "Other").

I use the following as a [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038589/populate-a-combobox-on-a-userform-from-cell-values), but it is not seeming to work.  Can anyone offer me advice?  When i run the `userform`, the `combobox` is not populated with anything.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("Other").range("C2:C11").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the wrong event procedure `ComboBox1_Change`. This fires only when the combobox changes value.

Instead, load the list when the userform initializes:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = [Other!C2:C11].Value
End Sub
```